# Problem with ARM package selection when installing homebrew git on an Intel MacBook Air

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew, open-source

I was trying to install homebrew git but I got this
`Error: Cannot install on Intel processor in ARM default prefix (/opt/homebrew)!`

I have an Intel processor MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2015) running macOS Monterey 12.6.5

To install brew - the first step seemed OK:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

I then want to install a different `git` with `brew install git` and that's when the error happens. What might I do to understand / fix this?

Comment: What is the result of `type brew; /usr/bin/uname -m`?

Comment: it is `brew is /opt/homebrew/bin/brew
x86_64`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason your homebrew installation ended up in the wrong directory. To fix, do the following

- `sudo rm -r /opt/homebrew`
- Quit (<kbd>Cmd-Q</kbd>) Terminal and restart it
- `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`

After the installation, run `type brew` again. If it returns `/usr/local/bin/brew`, you are all set.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot for helping : )